# How to override filter in child theme?

Tags: functions, filters, child-theme, pluggable

I'm trying to override a parent theme filter in a child theme; I must have the syntax wrong as the override is being completely ignored.  Here's what's in my child theme's functions.php:

```
//* remove and replace parent filter
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_filter('filter_name','parent_function');
}
add_filter('filter_name','child_function');

//* my custom function
function child_function($link){
    //* function code here
    return $link;
}
```

The child theme is definitely in use - I initially tried copying & customizing the function and got the 'cannot redeclare function' error. Just not sure why I can't replace the filter.

I even tried leaving just

```
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_filter('filter_name','parent_function');
}
```

to see if the outputted link would break but that didn't do anything either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you actually calling `child_remove_parent_function()` in your code.

Another issue to be aware of is timing. It is counter–intuitive, but `functions.php` files are loaded in order of **child first**, parent second.

Overall you need to ensure two things:

1. code works at all
2. it is called at the appropriate moment, after parent theme is done with its set up

Comment: OK - would I just need to add `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', ' child_remove_parent_function' );`?

Comment: I'm totally confused now. I know I can do this by editing the parent theme but that would be overridden by an update. Calling `child_remove_parent_function()` in my child theme's functions breaks the site.

Comment: Tried `function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_filter('filter_name','parent_function');
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_remove_parent_function' );` but still no dice. Can I get some help from someone?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and found the solution: to add a priority using the third parameter of the `add_action` function.

This is the definition of the function:

```
add_action( string $hook_name, callable $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 ): true
```

So, for example, instead of just:
`add_filter('filter_name','child_function');`
... this:
`add_filter('filter_name','child_function',20);`

I hope it helps!